# Why my app crashes when I launch it on android studio 1.2 but not in android studio 2.0 Preview

Tags: android, android-studio

When I launch my app on device with android studio 2.0 Preview it works fine, but then when I open android studio 1.2 and try to launch it , it doesnt Launch and it crashes? Does anyone have same problem or know how to fix this ? 
I get this error:

```
12-23 09:41:14.023  26953-26953/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 09:41:14.083    2025-2049/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: Post your crash report so one can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably occurs because of your android build tools and/or gradle configuration.
Can you check/change:

- The classpath of the android build tool you are using to build the app (e.g: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`)
- The buildToolVersion of your gradle script  (e.g: `buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'`)
- And finally if all these informations seems OK for you, you can check in this file `<project folder>/.idea/gradle.xml` the gradle_home.
  e.g:
  `<option name="gradleHome" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/gradle/gradle-2.4" />`

Comment: Can you accept the answer then? It can help other people :)